# Sitecore Solr Error undefined field tags

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

I am using Sitecore 8.1 with SOLR Search Provider. When I perform a search I am getting error below:

```
2480 2016:01:24 21:29:14 ERROR Solr Error : ["undefined field tags"] - Query  attempted: [((_basetemplates_sm:(13789a2000bc4f77a98f40d0a2f18738) AND

-standardvalue_b:(True)) AND ((title_t:(*smoking*))^9 OR (abstract_t: 

(*smoking*))^0.200000002980232 OR (articlefulltext_s: 

(*smoking*))^0.200000002980232 OR (title_t:(*be*))^9 OR (abstract_t: 

(*be*))^0.200000002980232 OR (articlefulltext_s:(*be*))^0.200000002980232 OR  

(tags:(d4426cf378c14a97be3459cd9bfe569b))^0.100000001490116))]
```

I believe the issue is that Sitecore API is somehow sending **tags** instead of **tags_sm**. When I manually update this field on SOLR Admin Portal query string, it returns data.

Now the real question is why/how the Sitecore API is sending tags instead of tags_sm. I had a look at schema.xml on web_index core, it has below:

```
<field name="_tags" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it your custom search query? Or built-in Sitecore query? For all fields starting with `_`, Sitecore does not append suffixes (like `_sm`). So the field in Solr will be `_tag` (you should be able to confirm this with Luke). Check if your `SearchResultItem` class (the one you pass to IQuerable), has a property with `[IndexField("tags")]` attribute and add undescore there.

Comment: Thanks @MarekMusielak, your solution worked. I  updated the attribute from tags to _tags it worked!

Comment: btw, how exactly does index field mapping works i.e. how can we tell whether to prefix with _.  And how does SOLR decide the name of the fields to index.

Comment: I've changed the comment into answer and added more explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all fields starting with `_`, Sitecore does not append suffixes (like `_sm`). So the field in Solr will be `_tags` (you should be able to confirm this with Luke).

Check if your `SearchResultItem` class (the one you pass to `IQuerable`), has a property with `[IndexField("tags")]` attribute and change it to `[IndexField("_tags")]`.

Also answering the other part of your question - you should never worry about what is the field name in Solr. Always use what is in Sitecore configuration for Sitecore built-in fields. And for your own fields, use their names lowercase. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and the fix is to match the field type defined in the backend. Ensure the code that triggers the search in C# has the right field type. In my case, I was trying to use ID type for tags when I switched it to Guid the name automatically suffixed with _sm while querying the index. Also ensure using correct collection type List worked compared to IEnumerable.

Side note the same code with field type as ID with IEnumerable worked in Lucene.

```
public class MySearchContentModel : SearchResultItem
{
        [IndexField(BuiltinFields.LatestVersion)]
        public bool IsLatestVersion { get; set; }

        [IndexField("Tag")]
        public List<Guid> Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The _sm tag will be added depending on the field type. Check Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration and the elements in /sitecore/contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/FieldMap/typeMatches

Here a list of ids are mapped to [fieldName]_sm in the typeName="guidCollection". Check that your configuration has this "_sm" extension. If it does you might want to check, that the map for "fieldNames" doesn't include the tags field name, so that it will not get the correct suffix.

If you change the config remember to rebuild the index.